# Why doesn't PHP Strict Standards complain about difference in constructor arguments?

Tags: php, constructor, strict

Normally when a child class has different function arguments that its parent, PHP Strict Standards lets you know:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of Boele::bla() should be compatible with Oele::bla($one, Exception $two) in foo.php

It doesn't break anything, but it lets you know that it's not cool. I agree.

However, constructors seem to get special treatment:

```php
class Oele {
  function __construct($one, Exception $two) {}

  function bla($one, Exception $two) {}
}

class Boele extends Oele {
  function __construct(Exception $two) {}

  function bla(Exception $two) {}
}
```

The `__construct()` and `bla()` methods are both different in parent and child, yet PHP only notifies about `bla()`, not about `__construct()`.

[Proof on 3v4l](http://3v4l.org/7H989)

**Why??** Isn't it equally 'bad' to do this for constructors?

(I'm running PHP 5.5.17 here, but as you can see on 3v4l it works the same for all PHP 5.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not explain why but there is an information in PHP documentation about this:

> Unlike with other methods, PHP will not generate an E_STRICT level error message when __construct() is overridden with different parameters than the parent __construct() method has.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Oh, wow, how did I not see that!? At least I know it's intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A major reason for this is that when you instantiate a class it calls the child constructor ONLY. If you want the parent constructor called as well, you have to explicitly call it by using `parent::__construct()`. It is assumed that child classes will build their own constructors and implement the parent as they see fit.

By contrast, if (using your example) I want to call `Boele->bla()`, it's potentially confusing to have two functions named the same with different arguments. Worse, there's not an easy way to call `Oele->bla()` using the child. So it's not considered a best practice to override a parent function with an incompatible function.

Consider also just how many ways PHP has a way to constrain implementation classes (abstract and interfaces). In these cases, you HAVE to implement them with the same arguments or you'll get an error.

Comment: Makes sense, sorta... I'm guessing I could force a constructor signature too with an interface?, not just methods?

Comment: I don't know of any way to force a child to load a parent constructor

Comment: That's not what I meant. If I create an interface with a constructor, all implementors must use that function signature, so you can force it anyway: http://3v4l.org/qWTDI

Comment: Ah, yes you can define what the constructor looks like with an interface